# What's wrong with strcpy()? (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c, string

What is wrong with `strcpy()` in this code?

```
void process_filedata(char *filename)
{
  void* content;
  const char * buffer;
  char * temp;
  char * row;
  char * col;
  int lsize,buflen,tmp,num_scan; //num_scan - number of characters scanned
  int m=0,p=0,d=0,j=0; //m - machine, p - phase, d- delimiter, j - job

  FILE *file_pointer = fopen("machinetimesnew.csv","r");

  if(file_pointer == NULL)
  {
   error_flag =  print_error("Error opening file");

   if(error_flag) exit(1);
  }
  fseek(file_pointer, 0 ,SEEK_END);
  lsize = ftell(file_pointer);
  buflen = lsize;
  rewind(file_pointer);
 // content = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*lsize);
  fread(content,1,lsize,file_pointer);
  buffer = (const char*) content;
  strcpy(temp,buffer);
  row = strtok(temp,"\n");
  ...............
  ...............
```

I am getting a segmentation fault..

Comment: Why is malloc commented?

Comment: Also realize that `buffer` is unnecessary. Just make `content` a `char*`.

Comment: Why the one letter var names?  If you took the time to comment their names, why not take the extra 2 seconds and save yourself and others future woes and name them correctly?

Comment: thanks everyone. I will make the changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually *three* segmentation faults here:

```
fread(content,1,lsize,file_pointer);
strcpy(temp,buffer);
row = strtok(temp,"\n");
```

The first one is `fread()` which is attempting to write to memory that does not yet exist as far as your process is concerned.

The second one is `strcpy()`, (expounding on the first) you are attempting to copy to a pointer that points to nothing. No memory (other than the pointer reference itself) has been allocated for `temp`, statically or dynamically.

Fix this via changing `temp` to look like this (allocating it statically):

```
char temp[1024];
```

Or use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate memory for it (as well as your other pointers, so they actually point to something), likewise for `content`. If you *know* the needed buffer size at compile time, use static allocation. If not, use `malloc()`. 'Knowing' is the subject of another question.

The third one is `strtok()` , which is going to modify `temp` *en situ* (in place), which it obviously can not do, since `temp` was never allocated. In any event, don't expect `temp` to be the same once `strtok()` is done with it. By the name of the variable, I assume you know that.

Also, *Initializing* a pointer is *not* the same thing as allocating memory for it:

```
char *temp = NULL; // temp is initialized
char *temp = (char *) malloc(size); // temp is allocated if malloc returns agreeably, cast return to not break c++
```

Finally, please get in the habit of using `strncpy()` over `strcpy()`, its much safer.

Comment: The `fread()` line is also incorrect, since `content` is uninitialised too.

Comment: @caf, I did say pointer`s` :) Updating, however.

Answer (score 13):

You're not allocating any space for temp.  It's a [wild pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Answer (score 8):

Nothing's wrong with strcpy. You haven't initialised `temp`.

Comment: Sure, but even the "safe" versions require that the input arguments should be actual values, not uninitialized junk. If there's anything wrong with `strcpy` here, the same thing is wrong with the entire C language. Once the first bug's fixed, we can worry about whether the data pointed to by `buffer` actually contains a NUL delimiter :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's yet another mistake. `fread` does not add a nul character to the end of the buffer. That's because it only deals with arrays of bytes, not nul-terminated strings. So you need to do something like this:

```
content = malloc(lsize + 1);
fread(content,1,lsize,file_pointer);
content[lsize] = 0;
temp = malloc(lsize + 1);
strcpy(temp, content);
```

or this:

```
content = malloc(lsize);
fread(content,1,lsize,file_pointer);
temp = malloc(lsize + 1);
memcpy(temp, content, lsize);
temp[lsize] = 0;
```

(Also, in real code you should check the results of `fread` and `malloc`.)

Answer (score 2):

you didn't allocate memory for temp

Answer (score 1):

`char * temp` hasn't been initialized and you consequently haven't allocated any memory for it.

try:

`temp = (char *)malloc(SIZE);`

where `SIZE` is however much memory you want to allocate for `temp`

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code intrigues me:

```
if(file_pointer == NULL)
{
   error_flag =  print_error("Error opening file");

   if(error_flag) exit(1);
}
```

Shouldn't you exit unconditionally if the file_pointer is NULL?

Comment: yeah.. That piece was incomplete. 
It goes this way.

error_flag = print_error(100); //ERROR 100: Error opening file! return 1

if(error_flag) exit(1);

Comment: @blacktooth, what is the use of modifying a (likely) non-atomic error_flag prior to just printing a nice error and exiting? Additionally, what is the use of making `exit()` reached only if the flag is high? Why not bail if `fopen()` returns a NULL pointer?

Comment: I thought of coding print_error function this way.

int print_error(int error_type)
{

  switch(error_type)
  {
    case 100: printf("Error opening File");
              return 1;
              break;
    case 101: printf("Invalid input! using default value zero");
              //something
              return 0;
              break;
    .......................
    .......................


Is it a bad idea?