# C strcpy does not work when copying to a pointer in a simple program?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *w;
    strcpy(w, "Hello Word");
    printf("%s\n", w);
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with the way the char pointer is used in the above code?

Comment: Not quite sure why you want to do that, but if a situation in which you need to do that comes up, you may find strdup() of use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584926/char-pointers-segmentation-fault , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868884/whats-wrong-with-strcpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you did not ask to the system for memory, to use it with the string. This code will work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
   char w[11];
   strcpy(w, "Hello Word");
   printf("%s\n", w);
   return 0;
}
```

That code declare w as an array of char, reserving the memory space for it. Other alternative is to use malloc or calloc for the char pointer. Read about that.

Answer (score 4):

You allocate no space for the string. w is just a pointer to some memory (garbage value since it's not initialized).

```
char w[32];
```

or

```
char *w = malloc(32);
```

You need to allocated the space for the characters.

Answer (score 3):

No memory allocated.

Add

```
w = (char *)malloc(42);
```

Comment: ( and don't forget to free() when you are finished with the memory )

Answer (score 3):

It's an uninitialized pointer.  The strcpy will write to some unknown location in memory.